# $c$ be algebraic , constructible over $\mathbb Q$ , $N$ be the normal closure of $\mathbb Q(c)/\mathbb Q$ ; then $[N:Q]$ is a power of $2$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

$c$ be algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ , $N$ be the normal closure of $\mathbb Q(c)/\mathbb Q$ ; if $c$ is constructible over rationals then how to show that $[N:\mathbb Q]$ is a power of $2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The field $N$ is $\Bbb Q(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ where the $c_j$ are the
conjugates of $c$. Now $c$ lies in a tower of quadratic extensions
of $\Bbb Q$. Therefore all the $c_j$ are also. Putting all these towers
together we get that $N$ is an iterated quadratic extension of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Is it obvious that [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) lie in the "quadratic closure" ?

Comment: If by "quadratic closure" you mean the field formed by all possible iterated quadratic extension, then yes, it is obvious.

Comment: Do we need to show that if $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}] = p$ is an odd prime then $a$ is not constructible ?

Comment: @user1952009 That's because $p$ is not a divisor of any power of $2$.